# How to stop the dribbling?

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

I am making a new breakout game using libGDX(I'm new to libGDX) and in the game whenever the ball touches the paddle it starts to dribble without bouncing on top of it.

I have already tried making changes to the ySpeed of the ball in this game.

Here is the code for my ball class.

```java
package com.thejavabay.my_game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;

public class Ball{

    int x;
    int y;
    int size;
    int xSpeed;
    int ySpeed;


    Circle cic = new Circle();



    Color color = Color.WHITE;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int size, int xSpeed, int ySpeed) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
        this.ySpeed = ySpeed;

    }

    public void update() {

        x += xSpeed;
        y += ySpeed;

        if (x < size || x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - size) 
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;


        if (y < size || y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - size) 
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;



    }

    public void draw(ShapeRenderer shape) { 


        cic.x = x;
        cic.y = y;
        cic.radius = size;

                shape.setColor(color);
                shape.circle(x, y, size);




        shape.circle(x, y, size);

    }

    private static boolean collidesWith(Paddle paddle, Ball ball) {

        if(Intersector.overlaps(ball.cic, paddle.rect))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public void checkCollision(Paddle paddle, Ball ball) {

        if(collidesWith(paddle, ball)) {

            ySpeed = -ySpeed;



        }





    }



}
```

I expected that the ball would bounce off the paddle but it keeps dribbing on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your order of execution is 
paint()->update()->checkCollision() or paint()->checkCollision->update()

due to this every third collision check after 1st ever collision will return true and your velocity will ping pong

and since you have circle.x in paint it will revert to original position every 2nd frame..fixed update should look like below..But before looking please work it out by your own.

```
public void update(){
    x += xSpeed;
    y += ySpeed;

    if (x < size || x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - size) 
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;


    if (y < size || y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - size) 
        ySpeed = -ySpeed; 

    cic.x = x;
    cic.y = y;
    cic.radius = size;

}
```

Comment: My order of execution is update() -> checkCollision() -> draw()

Comment: @wizard28082006 in that case too circle position is still that of last frame even though you have moved your ball in update ,  when checking collisions make sure that bounds of the object(circle , rect) are up to date with position and above solution should work..